# Facebook Shimmer integration error

Tags: android, facebook, declare-styleable

While integrating Facebook shimmer, when I tried the demo project it worked fine. But now when I integrated it in my actual project its giving me the following error:

> Error:(593) Attribute “shape” already defined with incompatible format

Can anyone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: may be library creates problem whatever you take in your project

Comment: I have observed that too. But i m looking for solution. If any other good shimmer library u know please let me know

Comment: how can i know which lib. you have used ?

Comment: 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.1.0@aar' i have used